# Can I make _Assert write to console instead of a message box?

Tags: scripting, automated-tests, autoit

I am writing a script in AutoIt to test a windows application, and I am using the [_Assert](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Assert.htm) function to verify certain actions.

In the documentation I found there is a parameter to say whether or not the script should end if an assertion fails, which is great because in some cases I would like the script to continue, but unfortunately it is still halted by a message box.

Can I override the _Assert function somehow to only print to the console when certain assertions fail, so the script can continue without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desired behavior can not be achieved using `_Assert()`. However, `_Assert()` can be *adjusted* to do so (replaced `MsgBox()` by `ConsoleWrite()`):

```
Func _AssertCustom($sCondition, $bExit = True, $nCode = 0x7FFFFFFF, $sLine = @ScriptLineNumber, Const $iCurERR = @error, Const $iCurEXT = @extended)
    Local $bCondition = Execute($sCondition)
    If Not $bCondition Then
        ConsoleWrite("Assertion Failed (Line " & $sLine & "): " & $sCondition & @CRLF)
        If $bExit Then Exit $nCode
    EndIf
    Return SetError($iCurERR, $iCurEXT, $bCondition)
EndFunc
```

Best to declare as new function (not to change Debug.au3).