# Debugging an AutoIt script or get currently executed script line number

Tags: autoit, script-debugging

My AutoIt script sends a list of clicks and key-presses to automate an old closed source application.

It has bugs so I want to know how I can debug AutoIt scripts. Or at least output the script's line number (to show code executed in real time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SciTE from Tools select “Trace: Add trace lines”. This will add a ConsoleWrite to each line if nothing is selected. If you select some code first it will add ConsoleWrite lines to what you have selected.

If you are getting an error in your compiled code you can add this to the top of your script before compiling it. When it errors out it will give you the right line number in your script.

```
#Au3Stripper_Parameters=/mo
```

Comment: The trace lines work good most of the time for debugging. If it gives you an error check to see if your code has any Select or Switch statements. You will want to remove any ConsoleWrite it might have added between the Select/Switch and the first Case.

Comment: My question was bad formulated, i was meaning i sometime dont have the right behavior in my code (a complex automation with synchronisation and blind windows (no text inside ...) ) so your answer is perfect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995360/autoit-error-handling/34000763#34000763

Comment: Make sure you are using the SciTE editor that has the extra utilities. The standard AutoIt install does not install it. [Here](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/) is the download page.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I debug AutoIt code?

### Syntax

#### Au3Check

As per [Documentation - Intro - AutoIt Syntax Checker (Au3Check)](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3check.htm):

> Checks the script for syntax errors.

Example:

```
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Au3Check_Parameters=-q -d -w 1 -w 2 -w 3 -w- 4 -w 5 -w 6 -w 7
```

Reports (almost) every non-runtime error, prior to execution and compile.

### Runtime

#### Current line

> … show me which code is executed in real time …

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `AutoItSetOption()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AutoItSetOption.htm):

> `TrayIconDebug` If enabled shows the current script line in the tray icon tip to help debugging.

Example:

```
AutoItSetOption("TrayIconDebug", 1)
```

#### Compiled scripts

[`#AutoIt3Wrapper_Run_Debug_Mode=Y`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/scite/docs/SciTE4AutoIt3/directives-available.html) runs script with console debugging.

Due to prepended include files, line numbers (in error messages) of compiled scripts do not match original .au3 file. As per [Documentation - SciTE4AutoIt3 - Au3Stripper](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/scite/docs/SciTE4AutoIt3/Au3Stripper.html):

> If there are no errors, run Au3Stripper to create an Stripped source file Scriptname_Stripped in the same folder containing all the source (the script and any #include files)

Example:

```
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Run_Au3Stripper=y
```

Line numbers in error messages of compiled scripts match those in `scriptname_stripped.au3` now (present after compile).

#### Error codes and return values

- [`ConsoleWrite()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ConsoleWrite.htm). Add `#AutoIt3Wrapper_Change2CUI=y` if to be read from compiled script.

  - [Macros of use](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm) include `@error`, `@extended` and `@ScriptLineNumber`
  - `SciTE4AutoIt3` > `Tools` > `Trace: Add Trace Lines` inserts such a command for every line. Displays current `@error` code (and concerning line).
  - `SciTE4AutoIt3` > `Tools` > `Debug to Console` (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) inserts such a command for currently selected line. Displays `@ScriptLineNumber`, return value and `@error` code. Executes original line a second time for its return value (may be undesired).
- [`VarGetType()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/VarGetType.htm) returns [the internal type representation of a variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30309114/4157124).
- [`_ArrayDisplay()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArrayDisplay.htm) to view structure and content of array variables.
- Possibly [log to file](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileWriteFromArray.htm) or [database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44659073/4157124) in case of remote debugging requirement.
- Error logging UDF's ([example](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/198929-autoit-error-logger-auerlo-udf/)) for simplification.

#### Assertions

As per [Documentation - User Defined Function Reference - `_Assert()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Assert.htm):

> Display a message if assertion fails

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30697499/4157124). Useful for regression tests and to verify edge cases and assumptions (or to simply abort in case of unexpected circumstances). Related functions include:

- [`IsBinary()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsBinary.htm)
- [`IsBool()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsBool.htm)
- [`IsDllStruct()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsDllStruct.htm)
- [`IsFloat()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsFloat.htm)
- [`IsHWnd()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsHWnd.htm)
- [`IsInt()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsInt.htm)
- [`IsNumber()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsNumber.htm)
- [`IsPtr()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsPtr.htm)
- [`IsString()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsString.htm)
- [`IsDeclared()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsDeclared.htm)
- [`IsFunc()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsFunc.htm)
- [`IsKeyWord()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsKeyword.htm)
- [`FileExists()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileExists.htm)

### Error handling

Generally functions return either- (or a combination of) [return value](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Func.htm) or [-error code](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/SetError.htm). Non `0` error code values (sometimes negative) signify failure. Return values (if used as such) alternate between `0` (failure) and `1` (success).

Handle errors as they appear. Scripts debug themselves provided for correct error handling. Avoid progressively nesting `If` -statements. Example:

```
Global Enum  $RANDOM_FLT, _
             $RANDOM_INT

Global Enum  $ERROR_OK, _
             $ERROR_AIR, _
             $ERROR_WATER, _
             $ERROR_FOOD, _
             $ERROR_ENUM

Global       $g_aError[$ERROR_ENUM]
             $g_aError[$ERROR_OK]    = 'survived'
             $g_aError[$ERROR_AIR]   = 'no air'
             $g_aError[$ERROR_WATER] = 'no water'
             $g_aError[$ERROR_FOOD]  = 'no food'

Global Const $g_sMsgConsole          = 'error:%i - %s\n'

While True
    Live()

    If @error Then
        ConsoleWrite(StringFormat($g_sMsgConsole, @error, $g_aError[@error])); And one of following:
        ContinueLoop
;       ExitLoop
;       Return; If in Local scope.
;       Exit @error
    EndIf

    ; Continuation conditional to successful execution of Live():
    ConsoleWrite(StringFormat($g_sMsgConsole, @error, $g_aError[@error]))
WEnd

Func Live()
    Local Const $iError    = Random($ERROR_OK, $ERROR_ENUM - 1, $RANDOM_INT), _
                $iExtended = 0, _
                $iReturn   = $iError ? 0 : 1

    Return SetError($iError, $iExtended, $iReturn)
EndFunc
```

Or [more specifically](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Switch.htm):

```
Live()

Switch @error

    Case $ERROR_AIR
        ; Handle specific error here.

    Case $ERROR_WATER
        ; Handle specific error here.

    Case $ERROR_FOOD
        ; Handle specific error here.

EndSwitch
```

Return values enable constructs like:

```
If Not SomeFunction() Then
    ; Handle here.
EndIf
; Continuation of script here.
```

Correlating error codes to text messages may help. Especially useful if shared among multiple related functions that call upon each other transparently returning encountered error codes (some `FindOnPage()` returning `$ERR_PAGELOAD` from a `LoadPage()` dependency for example).