# Database, relational query

Tags: database, search, autoit

Chemicals have a trade name (which is what it is commonly referred to as) and an actual chemical name. I need to look up a trade name, find its proper chemical name, then get properties of that chemical. For example:

```
$tradeName = "Voranol"

if $tradeName == "Voranol" then
    $productName = "Polyether Polyol"
    $flare = "List I"
    $bay = "1"
    $listPos = 3
EndIf
```

I have an .au3 file that contains a ton of products. It works fine but it's kind of tedious to do `if $tradeName == "Name1" or $tradeName == "Name2" or $tradeName == "Name4" or $tradeName == "Name5"`. I will also need to be able to edit it programmaticly. This is what I'm using now:

```
if $product == "dowanol pmb" or $product == "dowanol pma" or $product == "dipropylene glycol" or $product == "dowanol pnp" or $productCheck2 == "dowanol pmb" or $productCheck2 == "dowanol pma" or $productCheck2 == "dipropylene glycol" or $productCheck2 == "dowanol pnp" then
    $result = "DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL"
    $bay = 4
    $useFlare = 1
    $listPos = 2

elseif $product == "glycol blend" then
    $result = "GLYCOL"
    $bay = 3
    $useFlare = 2
    $listPos = 1

elseif $product == "isopar e" or $product == "isopar c" or $product == "isopar h" or $productCheck2 == "isopar h" then
    $result = "PETROLEUM NAPTHA"
    $bay = 5
    $useFlare = 0
    $listPos = 1 

EndIf
; Note: 0 = No Flare, 1 = Normal Flare, 2 = CAS Flare
```

Comment: You might use a csv-List (you can edit one in Excel quite comfortably) and read it with the `_FileReadToArray` [function](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileReadToArray.htm)...

Comment: That is something I was thinking about doing, but some chemicals have different trade names. For example, ethylene glycol can be called Dowanol PNP, Dowanol PN, or many other names (Not just Dowanol). I would need to have a way to update it dynamically to simply add a trade name to a product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative to the database option is to use an XML document to store the product (chemical) information.

You could easily query the XML with XPath to get the product name/properties. Maintaining the file would be fairly easy too. You could even create an XML Schema to validate against to be sure your file is still valid after modifications.

The processing of the XML in AutoIt can be done a few different ways:

- Creating an [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(v=vs.85).aspx) object
- Running a command line tool like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php)
- Using a XPath/XQuery/XSLT processor from the command line (i.e. java to run [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/))

Running something like Saxon is probably overkill for what you need.

MSXML wouldn't be too bad and there should be multiple UDFs that already exist.

Xmlstarlet would be my vote. (Note: I haven't used xmlstarlet in this fashion before. I'm a huge fan of Saxon and use it almost exclusively. Specifically for AutoIt, I've used a combination of MSXML and Saxon; Saxon to do the transforms of complicated data into a smaller, simpler subset and then MSXML to do simple xpath queries on that subset. However, if I was going to do something like this, I'd give xmlstarlet a serious look.)

Also, if your data grows to the point that a single XML file does not make sense, you could always split it into a collection of smaller files; individual products maybe. You might also reach a point that it might make sense to load those files into an actual XML database ([eXistdb](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/homepage/index.html) is an option).

Here's a simple example of what your XML (schema and instance) might look like:

**XSD** (products.xsd)

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="products">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="product"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="product">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="tradenames"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="bay" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="listpos" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="useflare" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="tradenames">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="name"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**XML** (products.xml)

```xml
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="products.xsd">
    <product bay="4" useflare="1" listpos="2">
        <name>DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL</name>
        <tradenames>
            <name>dowanol pmb</name>
            <name>dowanol pma</name>
            <name>dipropylene glycol</name>
            <name>dowanol pnp</name>
        </tradenames>
    </product>
    <product bay="3" useflare="2" listpos="1">
        <name>GLYCOL</name>
        <tradenames>
            <name>glycol blend</name>
        </tradenames>
    </product>
    <product bay="5" useflare="0" listpos="1">
        <name>PETROLEUM NAPTHA</name>
        <tradenames>
            <name>isopar e</name>
            <name>isopar c</name>
            <name>isopar h</name>
        </tradenames>
    </product>
</products>
```

Here's a little bit of AutoIt that uses MSXML to demonstrate loading the XML (validates against XSD) and searching for products that have a trade name that contains "glycol".

**AutoIt**

```
;~  AutoIt Version: 3.3.14.2

;String to search on.
$searchString = "glycol"
ConsoleWrite("Search string: '" & $searchString & "'" & @CRLF)

;XPath for searching trade names. Search string is injected (code injection; escaping of strings would be a very good idea!).
$xpath_tradename = "/products/product[tradenames/name[contains(.,'" & $searchString & "')]]"
ConsoleWrite("XPath: '" & $xpath_tradename & "'" & @CRLF)

$msxml = ObjCreate('MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0')
If IsObj($msxml) Then
    $msxml.async = False
    $msxml.validateOnParse = True
    $msxml.resolveExternals = True
    $msxml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")
    $msxml.load('products.xml')
    If $msxml.parseError.errorCode = 0 Then
        $prods = $msxml.SelectNodes($xpath_tradename)
        If IsObj($prods) And $prods.Length > 0 Then
            ConsoleWrite("Number of products found: '" & $prods.Length & "'" & @CRLF)
            For $prod In $prods
                ConsoleWrite(@CRLF & "------ PRODUCT ------" & @CRLF)
                ConsoleWrite("Product name: '" & $prod.SelectSingleNode('name').text & "'" & @CRLF)
                ConsoleWrite("Product bay: '" & $prod.getAttribute('bay') & "'" & @CRLF)
            Next
            ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
        Else
            ConsoleWrite("PRODUCT NOT FOUND" & @CRLF)
        EndIf
    Else
        MsgBox(17, 'Error', 'Error opening XML file: ' & @CRLF & @CRLF & $msxml.parseError.reason)
        SetError($msxml.parseError.errorCode)
    EndIf
EndIf
```

**Console Output**

```
Search string: 'glycol'
XPath: '/products/product[tradenames/name[contains(.,'glycol')]]'
Number of products found: '2'

------ PRODUCT ------
Product name: 'DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL'
Product bay: '4'

------ PRODUCT ------
Product name: 'GLYCOL'
Product bay: '3'
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105210/discussion-between-timothy-bomer-and-daniel-haley).

Answer (score 1):

The best database solution in Autoit is SQLite.

If you want to do it like a pro, you should use SQLite.

```
#include <SQLite.au3>
#include <SQLite.dll.au3>

Local $hQuery, $aRow
_SQLite_Startup()
ConsoleWrite("_SQLite_LibVersion=" & _SQLite_LibVersion() & @CRLF)
_SQLite_Open()
; Without $sCallback it's a resultless statement
_SQLite_Exec(-1, "Create table tblTest (a,b int,c single not null);" & _
        "Insert into tblTest values ('1',2,3);" & _
        "Insert into tblTest values (Null,5,6);")

Local $d = _SQLite_Exec(-1, "Select rowid,* From tblTest", "_cb") ; _cb will be called for each row

Func _cb($aRow)
    For $s In $aRow
        ConsoleWrite($s & @TAB)
    Next
    ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
    ; Return $SQLITE_ABORT ; Would Abort the process and trigger an @error in _SQLite_Exec()
EndFunc   ;==>_cb
_SQLite_Close()
_SQLite_Shutdown()

; Output:
; 1     1   2   3
; 2         5   6
```

As a simpler solution I would recommend using INI file as database.

```
[Voranol]
ProductName=Polyether Polyol
Flare=List I
Bay=1
ListPos=3

[Chem2]
ProductName=..
...
```

And then

```
   ; Read the INI section names. This will return a 1 dimensional array.
    Local $aArray = IniReadSectionNames($sFilePath)

    ; Check if an error occurred.
    If Not @error Then
        ; Enumerate through the array displaying the section names.
        For $i = 1 To $aArray[0]
            MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Section: " & $aArray[$i])
        Next
    EndIf
```

Now there is a limit in windows on INI file size(32kb).
That means, certain Autoit INI functions will not work if that limit is breached.

This can be solved by using your own INI functions:

```
Func _IniReadSectionNamesEx($hFile)
    Local $iSize = FileGetSize($hFile) / 1024
    If $iSize <= 31 Then
        Local $aNameRead = IniReadSectionNames($hFile)
        If @error Then Return SetError(@error, 0, '')
        Return $aNameRead
    EndIf
    Local $aSectionNames = StringRegExp(@CRLF & FileRead($hFile) & @CRLF, '(?s)\n\s*\[(.*?)\]s*\r', 3)
    If IsArray($aSectionNames) = 0 Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    Local $nUbound = UBound($aSectionNames)
    Local $aNameReturn[$nUbound + 1]
    $aNameReturn[0] = $nUbound
    For $iCC = 0 To $nUBound - 1
        $aNameReturn[$iCC + 1] = $aSectionNames[$iCC]
    Next
    Return $aNameReturn
EndFunc

Func _IniReadSectionEx($hFile, $vSection)
    Local $iSize = FileGetSize($hFile) / 1024
    If $iSize <= 31 Then
        Local $aSecRead = IniReadSection($hFile, $vSection)
        If @error Then Return SetError(@error, 0, '')
        Return $aSecRead
    EndIf
    Local $sFRead = @CRLF & FileRead($hFile) & @CRLF & '['
    $vSection = StringStripWS($vSection, 7)
    Local $aData = StringRegExp($sFRead, '(?s)(?i)\n\s*\[\s*' & $vSection & '\s*\]\s*\r\n(.*?)\[', 3)
    If IsArray($aData) = 0 Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    Local $aKey = StringRegExp(@LF & $aData[0], '\n\s*(.*?)\s*=', 3)
    Local $aValue = StringRegExp(@LF & $aData[0], '\n\s*.*?\s*=(.*?)\r', 3)
    Local $nUbound = UBound($aKey)
    Local $aSection[$nUBound +1][2]
    $aSection[0][0] = $nUBound
    For $iCC = 0 To $nUBound - 1
        $aSection[$iCC + 1][0] = $aKey[$iCC]
        $aSection[$iCC + 1][1] = $aValue[$iCC]
    Next
    Return $aSection
EndFunc
```

Answer (score -1):

> I need to look up a trade name, find its proper chemical name, then get properties of that chemical.

## Relational query ([SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/about.html))

- [SQL as understood by SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang.html).
- If requirements are limited to inserts, edits and queries, an [SQLite database management tool](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=sqlite+database+management+tool) may suffice. AutoIt SQLite functions are documented as per [User-defined function-reference](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions.htm):

1. (Create and) open database using [`_SQLite_Open()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_SQLite_Open.htm).
2. Create tables , indexes and view(s) (and insert records) using [`_SQLite_Exec()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_SQLite_Exec.htm).
3. Queries using [`_SQLite_GetTable2d()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_SQLite_GetTable2d.htm) return results as two-dimensional array.

### Structure

[SQLite data types](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Inserting records to `product` and `substance` table may be [automated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049076/quick-easy-way-to-convert-all-of-these-to-variables/44511842#44511842).

[image]

#### Table `product`

Defines trade names.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dowanol pmb |
| 2 | dowanol pma |
| 3 | dipropylene glycol |
| 4 | dowanol pnp |
| 5 | glycol blend |
| 6 | isopar e |
| 7 | isopar c |
| 8 | isopar h |
| 9 | Polyether Polyol |
| 10 | Voranol |

Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
   id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   name TEXT    UNIQUE
);
```

Insert record:

```
INSERT INTO product (name) VALUES ('dowanol pmb');
```

#### Table `substance`

Defines chemical names (and properties).

| id | name | flare | bay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Polyether Polyol | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | GLYCOL | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | PETROLEUM NAPHTA | 0 | 5 |

Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS substance (
   id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   name  TEXT    UNIQUE,
   flare INTEGER,
   bay   INTEGER
);
```

Insert record:

```
INSERT INTO substance (name, flare, bay) VALUES ('Polyether Polyol', 1, 1);
```

#### Table `relation`

Defines relations between `product` and `substance` table's records (using [foreign keys](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)).

| id | product | substance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 10 | 1 |

Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS relation (
   id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   product   INTEGER REFERENCES product(id),
   substance INTEGER REFERENCES substance(id),
   UNIQUE(  /* Constraint applies to *combination* of columns. */
      product,
      substance
   )
);
```

Insert record:

```
INSERT INTO relation (
   product,
   substance
) VALUES (
   (SELECT id FROM product   WHERE name = 'dowanol pmb'),
   (SELECT id FROM substance WHERE name = 'DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL')
);
```

Or just:

```
INSERT INTO relation (product, substance) VALUES (0, 1);
```

#### View `view_relation`

[View](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) ([stored query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL))), [joining](https://sqlite.org/syntax/join-operator.html) ([combines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))) `product` and `substance` tables' fields, as per `relation` table's records (acting as virtual table, negating need to include underlying `JOIN` operators every query).

| name_product | name_substance | flare | bay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dowanol pmb | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |
| dowanol pma | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |
| dipropylene glycol | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |
| dowanol pnp | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |
| glycol blend | GLYCOL | 2 | 3 |
| isopar e | PETROLEUM NAPTHA | 0 | 5 |
| isopar c | PETROLEUM NAPTHA | 0 | 5 |
| isopar h | PETROLEUM NAPTHA | 0 | 5 |
| Polyether Polyol | PETROLEUM NAPTHA | 0 | 5 |
| Voranol | Polyether Polyol | 1 | 1 |

Creation:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS view_relation AS
   SELECT
      product.name    AS name_product,
      substance.name  AS name_substance,
      substance.flare,
      substance.bay
   FROM
      relation
   LEFT OUTER JOIN product   ON relation.product   = product.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN substance ON relation.substance = substance.id
   ORDER BY
      product.id ASC
;
```

#### Query by trade name

| name_product | name_substance | flare | bay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Voranol | Polyether Polyol | 1 | 1 |

Query:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   view_relation
WHERE
   name_product = 'Voranol'
;
```

Or (without view):

```
SELECT
   product.name    AS name_product,
   substance.name  AS name_substance,
   substance.flare,
   substance.bay
FROM
   relation
WHERE
   product.name = 'Voranol'
LEFT OUTER JOIN product   ON relation.product   = product.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN substance ON relation.substance = substance.id
;
```

#### Query by substance

| name_product | name_substance | flare | bay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dowanol pmb | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |
| dowanol pma | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |
| dipropylene glycol | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |
| dowanol pnp | DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL | 1 | 4 |

Query:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   view_relation
WHERE
   name_substance = 'DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL'
;
```

Or (without view):

```
SELECT
   product.name    AS name_product,
   substance.name  AS name_substance,
   substance.flare,
   substance.bay
FROM
   relation
WHERE
   substance.name = 'DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL'
LEFT OUTER JOIN product   ON relation.product   = product.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN substance ON relation.substance = substance.id
;
```

### AutoIt

Example creating (and inserting records to) a single table and query it:

```
#include <SQLite.au3>
#include <SQLite.dll.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $g_iRecords   = 50
Global Const $g_sFileDb    = @ScriptDir & '\example.sqlite'
Global       $g_aCreate    = [ _
                             'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);' & @LF, _
                             '--CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_example_name ON example(name);' & @LF _
                             ]
Global Const $g_sInsert    = 'INSERT INTO example (name) VALUES (%i);\n'
Global Const $g_sTransact1 = 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;' & @LF
Global Const $g_sTransact2 = 'END TRANSACTION;' & @LF
Global Const $g_sQuery     = 'SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY id ASC;'
Global Const $g_sMsgError  = 'sqlite.dll not found.' & @LF

Global       $g_hDb        = 0

Main()

Func Main()
    Local $sQuery     = ''
    Local $iResultCol = 0
    Local $iResultRow = 0
    Local $aResult

    For $i1 = 0 To UBound($g_aCreate, 1) -1
        $sQuery &= $g_aCreate[$i1]
    Next

    For $i1 = 1 To $g_iRecords
        $sQuery &= StringFormat($g_sInsert, _SQLite_FastEscape('example' & $i1))
    Next

    $sQuery = $g_sTransact1 & $sQuery & $g_sTransact2
    ConsoleWrite($sQuery)

    _SQLite_Startup()
    If @error Then
        ConsoleWrite($g_sMsgError)
        Exit
    EndIf

    _SQLite_Open($g_sFileDb)
    _SQLite_Exec($g_hDb, $sQuery)
    _SQLite_GetTable2d($g_hDb, $g_sQuery, $aResult, $iResultRow, $iResultCol)
    _SQLite_Close($g_hDb)
    _SQLite_Shutdown()

    _ArrayDisplay($aResult)
    Exit
EndFunc
```