# Unable to CREATE TABLE; why does this code fail?

Tags: sqlite, autoit

I have a problem with SQLite v3.22.0 and AutoIt v3.3.14.3. Trying to create a database works but the table does not get created. I use the AutoIt example code:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <SQLite.au3>
#include <SQLite.dll.au3>

Local $hQuery, $aRow, $sMsg
_SQLite_Startup()
ConsoleWrite("_SQLite_LibVersion=" & _SQLite_LibVersion() & @CRLF)
_SQLite_Open() ; open :memory: Database
_SQLite_Exec(-1, "CREATE TABLE aTest (a,b,c);") ; CREATE a Table
_SQLite_Exec(-1, "INSERT INTO aTest(a,b,c) VALUES ('c','2','World');") ; INSERT Data
_SQLite_Exec(-1, "INSERT INTO aTest(a,b,c) VALUES ('b','3',' ');") ; INSERT Data
_SQLite_Exec(-1, "INSERT INTO aTest(a,b,c) VALUES ('a','1','Hello');") ; INSERT Data
_SQLite_Query(-1, "SELECT c FROM aTest ORDER BY a;", $hQuery) ; the query
While _SQLite_FetchData($hQuery, $aRow) = $SQLITE_OK
    $sMsg &= $aRow[0]
WEnd
_SQLite_Exec(-1, "DROP TABLE aTest;") ; Remove the table
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "SQLite", "Get Data using a Query : " & $sMsg)
_SQLite_Close()
_SQLite_Shutdown()

; Output:
; Hello World
```

If I request the SQLite error, I get "Library used incorrectly". What's the problem in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoIt [v3.3.14.3 has a bug](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/192242-sqlite-examples-are-not-working-correctly-in-autoit-33143/#comment-1379534); install AutoIt v3.3.14.2 or [get the bug-fix](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/192254-33143-fixes/).

Answer (score 0):

> Whats the problem in this case?

As per [Documentation - Script breaking changes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/script_breaking_changes.htm) :

> `_SQLite_Startup()` function no longer automatically downloads the SQLite DLL files from autoitscript.com. Most users were completely unaware that this download was occuring on each script run and it was also a severe bandwidth hog for the website. The SQLite DLLs must now be manually download. See the [`_SQLite_Startup()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_SQLite_Startup.htm) documentation for details.

If `_SQLite_Startup()`'s first parameter is omitted, then dll file must reside in `@SystemDir`, `@WindowsDir`, `@ScriptDir` or `@WorkingDir` for this function to succeed.

1. [Download `sqlite3.dll`](http://sqlite.org/download.html),
2. remove `#include <SQLite.dll.au3>`, then
3. provide `_SQLite_Startup()`'s first parameter with location of dll file (redundant if present in one of four previously mentioned locations).

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44659073/4157124).

Comment: Tried now many possible solutions. None of them works. If i try to get the lib version i get 3.22.0 so the library is there and is loaded but all actions i run with autoit are failing.