# _ScreenCapture_Capture() fails, presumably due to missing GDI+ encoders

Tags: screenshot, autoit

I would like to do a screen capture using AutoIt. My code:

```
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
_ScreenCapture_Capture(@ScriptDir & "/test.jpg")
```

This doesn't work. And I know why. I tested what encoders I have:

```
#include <GDIPlus.au3>
$Encoders = _GDIPlus_Encoders()
MsgBox(0, "", UBound($Encoders))
```

The result is: `0`. So why don't I have any encoders? And how can I get any?

Comment: The encoders result is also zero on my system, but the screenshot gets saved, so your problem must be an other. (Note: you should use `\` as folder delimter, not `/` (although it works in most cases, the correct way on Windows is `\`)

Comment: PS: The error code is -2.

Comment: what does `ConsoleWrite( _WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics($__SCREENCAPTURECONSTANT_SM_CYSCREEN) & @CRLF)` return? Do you have a multi-monitor environment?

Comment: how I get the $__SCREENCAPTURECONSTANT_SM_CYSCREEN variable?

Comment: `#include <ScreenCapture.au3>`

Comment: so i write this: `#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <Screencapture.au3>

$h = ConsoleWrite( _WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics($__SCREENCAPTURECONSTANT_SM_CYSCREEN) & @CRLF)
MsgBox(0, "", $h)` and the MsgBox Displays 5.

Comment: and `MsgBox(0, "", _WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics($__SCREENCAPTURECONSTANT_SM_CYSCREEN))` Displays 768

Comment: Theory failed... `_ScreenCapture_Capture` returns @error -2, when the bottom value (786 in your case) is less than top value (zero in your case). Let me overthink it tomorrow - 11:15pm here...

Comment: `_ScreenCapture_Capture` returns @error =-2 when `$iBottom > $iTop`. By default, Bottom is -1, which is translated to the screen height (the command I gave you yesterday to test). Default for Top is 0. So this really shouldn't happen. Try to give it the four optional screen values (like `_ScreenCapture_Capture(@ScriptDir & "/test.jpg", 0, 0, 1366, 768)` (if that's your screen resolution). Note: my `ScreenCapture.au3` has a date of 17-sep-2015 and a size of 10.923 bytes

Comment: no its @error=2 and the screencapture function returns False. With your example function.

Comment: this `$screen = _ScreenCapture_Capture("")

$gui = GUICreate("hello", @DesktopWidth / 2, @DesktopHeight / 2)
GUISetState()

_GDIPlus_Startup()
$bmp = _GDIPlus_BitmapCreateFromHBITMAP($screen)
$graphic = _GDIPlus_GraphicsCreateFromHWND($gui)
_GDIPlus_GraphicsDrawImage($graphic, $bmp, 0, 0)

Do
Until GUIGetMsg() = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE` works. The Problem is to save the Bitmap as an Image file.

Comment: sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The encoder result is "0" for me too, but like in Stephan's case, the screenshot gets saved. I would recommend asking this at the AutoIt forum.
[link]https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/

Comment: _GDIPlus_Encoders() will not return 0 if you run _GDIPlus_Startup() first

Comment: Try the example code from the help page for [_ScreenCapture_Capture()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ScreenCapture_Capture.htm). Does this work?

Comment: no the example at the page also doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

> This doesn't work. And I know why.

AutoIt v3.3.14.3 has a bug. Install [latest version](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) and it should work. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037862/4157124).